Count the number of red candles for trigger the order

hello team,
i was looking for a small condition where on the above image order should't trigger on candle A
but order should trigger at candle B
In other word A candle having previous 5 and more red candle
but candle B have less that 5
Expecting a small condition code

Please let us know the language you want to achieve this.

Do you have any code that generates the chart already?

@AkhilSuthapalli sir i was looking in to c#

@phuzi yes sir i have it's like i need compaire with all previous candle open > close but i was looking for some condiion

Can you add some of your code to the question so that we may take a look.
